# jQuery can't find nested image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="showDropZone" class="ui-droppable" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; outline-style: none; left: 0px; width: 379px; height: 500px;">
    <div id="introText" style="display: none;">Drag and drop program images here</div>
        <ul class="gallery ui-helper-reset">
            <li class="imgThumbLi ui-draggable imageSelected" title="File Name: drago.jpg Dimension: 225x225 Size: 7 KB" style="display: list-item;">
                <img class="image" src="/myApp/2012/5/1/1335900424140/39345e7f3d12487bb6e347e786194c9b" title="File Name: drago.jpg Dimension: 225x225 Size: 7 KB">
                <div class="imageInfo">
                    <p class="detailTitle">Logo!</p>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my jQuery/JS function I obtain the `<ul>` element (and its `<li>` children) and I can easily find the `p.detailTitle`'s text value with the following code:

```
$("#showDropZone").find("ul").each(function() {
    $(this).find("li").each(function() {
        var detailTitle = $(this).find("p.detailTitle").text();

        // This prints "Logo!" correctly...
        alert(detailTitle);

        var imageTitle = $(this).find("img").title;
        var imageSrc = $(this).find("img").src;

        // But these both print "undefined"...
        alert(imageTitle);
        alert(imageSrc);
    }
}
```

How do I get the `<img>`'s `title` and `src` attributes? As indicated in the code above, the current code returns them as `undefined`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `.attr()`

Refer: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Working Code:

```
$("#showDropZone").find("ul").each(function() {

alert($(this).html());
    $(this).find("li").each(function() {
        var detailTitle = $(this).find("p.detailTitle").text();

        // This prints "Logo!" correctly...
        alert(detailTitle);

        var imageTitle = $(this).find("img").attr('title');
        var imageSrc = $(this).find("img").attr('src');

        // But these both print "undefined"...
        alert(imageTitle);
        alert(imageSrc);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shortened version. Here, I take advantage of the second parameter of the `$()` which is to specify the context of the search. In this code's `each()`, the value of `this`  is the DOM element `li` at that current iteration. We use `this` as our "base" to narrow the search instead of using `find()`.

```
$("#showDropZone ul > li").each(function() {

    var detailTitle = $("p.detailTitle", this).text(); //find detailTitle in <li>
    var img = $("img", this);                          //find img in <li>
    var imageTitle = img.attr('title'); 
    var imageSrc = img.attr('src');

    alert(detailTitle);
    alert(imageTitle);
    alert(imageSrc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
var imageTitle = $(this).find("img").attr('title');
var imageSrc = $(this).find("img").attr('src');
```

or

```
var imageTitle = $(this).find("img")[0].title;
var imageSrc = $(this).find("img")[0].src;
```

I think your problem is that the `find` function will return a jQuery wrapped DOM element that does not have `title` or `src` properties. Using jQuery's `attr` function or converting the returned values back to 'plain' Javscript DOM objects should fix your problem.

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/PSzE3/

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting all images instead of choosing just one and accessing its values/attributes. Try:

```
var imageTitle = $(this).find('img').get(0).attr('title');
var imageSrc = $(this).find('img').get(0).attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery find function which returns array of result instead of single element.
Think of the case when there is 5 img tag in your html and you say jQuery to bring img and display its title!!!...

So update your script code like

```
$("#showDropZone").find("ul").each(function() {
$(this).find("li").each(function() {
    var detailTitle = $(this).find("p.detailTitle").text();

    // This prints "Logo!" correctly...
    alert(detailTitle);

    $(this).find("img").each(function(){
        var imageTitle = this.title;
        var imageSrc = this.src;

    // wollaaaa working exactly...
    alert(imageTitle);
    alert(imageSrc);
    });

});
});
```

alternatively if you just want to test on your code just use

```
var imageTitle = $(this).find("img")[0].title;
var imageSrc = $(this).find("img")[0].src;
```

this will work in above html as it is having single image.